# Update query's where clause values from a datatable

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, system.data.datatable

I have this `query`:

```
UPDATE A
Set A.NUM = B.NUM
FROM A
JOIN B  on A.ID = B.ID
where A.Code in ()
```

`A.Code` values are from a `datatable`.  How do I feed into this `query`?

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is in the parenthesis. I need to feed values from a datatable. Something like (select column1 from datatable)

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/337792/575376

Comment: Is that a C# datatable or SQL Table?

Comment: @juergend That's old now. Table-valued parameters are the new hotness, _especially_ if you already have a datatable.

Comment: It is a .NET DataTable.  Be specific with the correct capitalization.  Is it just he value for the first row or all rows.

Answer (score 2):

Why not write a code to make a comma separated string of ID's using datatable?

```
            string lstOfIDs = string.Empty;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
            {
                lstOfIDs += drow["IdColumnHere"].ToString()+",";
            }

            lstOfIDs.TrimEnd(',');
```

You can then pass the lstOfIds in the IN clause.

**EDIT 1:**

I think `A.Code In ()` is checking for code not Ids. I hope you are placing codes in the lstOfIDs. Also, I would advise putting ' between Id's. i.e.

```
lstOfIDs += "'"+drow["IdColumnHere"].ToString()+"',";
```

this should give you something like 'abc','def','anything'

Comment: This method is not working for me. Too many IDs in the parenthesis caused the string would be truncated error. Also, the way to add comma is causing syntax error. it should be added in front of the value.

Comment: Please check the edit. In case that doesn't work share your code.

Answer (score 1):

You want a [Table-Valued Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This article will also help:

> http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/02/using-sql-servers-table-valued-parameters/

If you have more columns than just `Code` in the C# Datatable, you may also need a projection (inside the sql) get output that will work with the `IN()` clause. Something like this:

```
UPDATE A
Set A.NUM = B.NUM
FROM A
JOIN B  on A.ID = B.ID
where A.Code in ( SELECT Code FROM @tvpCodes )
```

Comment: I defined the Type and it kept complaining the type does not exist:
so I add this line "Create TYPE dbo.MyTableType as TABLE( Code int);" in front of the query I had. and then use standard sql command to update it doesn't work.